# UITableView reselects row when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, modalviewcontroller

I've got a tableView with static cells. The modalCell (see screenshot) has a segue to a viewController that the `tableViewController` presents modally. If I dismiss the modal view, the cell gets deselected. However, when I scroll the cell out of the screen and scroll back so that it appears again, the cell is selected again. I reproduced this behavior in a fresh example project.

Here is my storyboard setup (nothing fancy):
[image: storyboard setup]

My Code in `ViewController` looks like so:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var modalCell: UITableViewCell!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath), cell == modalCell {
            modalCell.setSelected(false, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
}
```

In the screen recording, you can see that the cell deselects correctly. However, if I scroll, the cell is selected again. Any ideas why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just deselect cell in table view

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: so, what is then the difference between `tableViewCell.setSelected(:)`, `tableViewCell.isSelected = false`and `tableView.deselectRow(at:)`?